# Display Javascript Function Result inside of API Data Object?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, express

So I have my input forms that have a fixed value, so when I fill out my form it will showcase my order value properly. However, this doesn't include my taxes, fees etc. in the order total.

Example input

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="item1" value="10" onClick="updatePrice()">
    <label for="item1">12 piece wings $10</label>
```

The value is $10, so when I add this to my express API function

```
 {
    name: req.body.name,
    order_value: req.body.item1,
   }
```

It will show in my console.log the order value of $10

However, I wrote this JS function to include delivery fees + taxes etc.

```
function updatePrice() {
    let items = 0;
    let deliveryFee = 0;
    let tax = document.getElementById('tax')    
    let tip = document.getElementById('tip')

    tax = .07
    tip = .2

    document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(checkBox => {
        if (checkBox.checked) {
            items += +checkBox.value
           if(deliveryFee == 0) {
               deliveryFee = 1.99
           }
        }
    })

    if (items >= 20) {
        deliveryFee = deliveryFee + 3;
      }

      let orderTotal = (items * tax)+(items * tip)+(items) + deliveryFee;
     

    document.getElementById("price").textContent = `Food Total: $${(items).toFixed(2)}`;
    document.getElementById("tax").textContent = `Tax (7%): $${(items * tax).toFixed(2)}`;
    document.getElementById("tip").textContent = `Tip (20%): $${(items * tip).toFixed(2)}`;
    document.getElementById("fee").textContent = `Delivery Fee: $${(deliveryFee).toFixed(2)}`;
    document.getElementById("total").textContent = `Your order total is: $${(orderTotal).toFixed(2)}`;
}
```

Then in my index.html I have this for my total

```
<p id="total" name="total">Your order total is: $0.00</p>
```

So on my browser, it will show on the text the order total ending up being $14.69

However, if I try to add that to my express function

```
 {
    name: req.body.name,
    order_value: req.body.total,
   }
```

This doesn't work or even do anything because I am guessing it is just a simple p tag and I don't know how to get the total from the JS function to display onto my express API file?

How would I include the additional fees to showcase in my total cost for my API?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a hidden form element `<input type="hidden" name="total" id="totalform">` and fill that with an additional Javascript statement `document.getElementById("totalform").value = ...`.

But you must be aware that calculating such things in Javascript on the frontend can only serve a better user experience. The backend *must not* rely on computations done on the frontend, because these can always be manipulated by a malicious user. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72130824/16462950.

I would therefore find it OK if you display the total only in a `<p>` element, do not send it to the backend but rather compute it there again.

Here is a simplified example that does not use Javascript on the client but instead reloads the page after every interaction:

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}), function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.product = req.body.product;
  res.locals.quantity = req.body.quantity;
  next();
})
.post("/action", async function(req, res, next) {
  switch (res.locals.product) {
    case "Chalk": res.locals.price = 3 * res.locals.quantity; break;
    case "Cheese": res.locals.price = 5 * res.locals.quantity; break;
  }
  if (req.body.order) {
    var {product, quantity, price} = res.locals;
    // await write {product, quantity, price} to database;
  }
  next();
})
.use(function(req, res) {
  res.type("html");
  res.end(`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="action" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  Product <input name="product" value="${res.locals.product || ""}"/><br/>
  Quantity <input name="quantity" value="${res.locals.quantity || ""}"/><br/>
  Price <input name="price" readonly  value="${res.locals.price || ""}"/>
  <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calculate Price"/>
  <input type="submit" name="order" value="Order"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>`);
});
```

Comment: hmm so regarding my pricing calculations, if I am using an API that is supposed to do all those calculations, how would you design the front end to showcase the correct value on my front end app? do you have an example of what you mean back calculation the total on the backend for an app?

Comment: See my augmented answer.

Comment: right but wouldn't this be implying a fixed cost of a product? How would I include a tax, delivery fee etc on top of the product total to be sent to the API backend? since 1 egg * $3 would still equal $3 and not include a tax of 7% or delivery fee of $5 for example so in reality the total is like $8.21

Comment: Mine was a _simplified_ example. The code in the `/action` route can of course be much more complex, you may also need more `<form>` elements.

Comment: yeah cause that's my issue is I have my front end form that sends my input data to my API and updates it like normal, so I can already get the price to show $5, but my problem is trying to get the taxes, fees etc added to the order total so my API shows the correct value

Comment: My simple example "derives" the price from the product (Chalk costs 3, Cheese costs 5). Taxes and fees must also be determined by code that runs in the backend.

Comment: hmm from the API, it doesn't show any list of taxes or fees etc on the documents so if I am making a front end app integrating with their API, how would I even display those fees if the only object data that I can find is order total or fee