# How would I secure a POST route for a web game?

Tags: node.js, json, api, rest, express

I am currently learning full stack dev, and have made a simple application with React on the front end, and set up a very simple REST api on my express web server that handles certain routes.

For example api/users returns a list of users from my database and returns responses as JSON data. api/blogs can return a list of blogs in JSON with a get request, or post a blog with a post request.

Say in my application, a game, a user has value of `gold` which is stored in the DB with their username and other game info. In the game if they unlock something or 'win', their gold gets updated. I would assume I would have to make a PUT request to the `api/users` and edit their gold amount to the database. But I am dreadfully concern, couldnt they always just make a PUT request from the outside and increase their `gold` at will? What possible ways exist to authenticate this route only from the server or allowed? This part makes 0 sense to me

I have learned and been able to implement very basic user tokenization with JWT, and so only logged in users with a valid token can make a post of a blog for example. This is done by adding their token with bearer as a Authentication header in the request, which the server verifies.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds as if the Javascript code that runs on the frontend would decide that a user has earned 10 pieces of gold, say, and you then want to inform the backend about the decision in a secure manner. That will not work, for the reasons outlined in [When doing a booking system, where would it be better to do? Back end or front end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72130746/when-doing-a-booking-system-where-would-it-be-better-to-do-back-end-or-front-e).

It highly depends on the nature of your game and its rules for earning gold how this could be implemented securely. For example, if you earn 10 pieces gold by solving a mathematical puzzle within 1 minute, it could work like this:

- The backend comes up with a puzzle "What are the prime factors of 2758238235918?" and stores the expected answer together with the deadline in its database, e.g.

  ```json
  {"user": "oscar",
  "puzzleID": "ab45ga4753",
  "answer": [2, 3, 3, 11, 71, 7993, 24547],
  "deadline": "2022-07-09T20:11:00+02:00"}
  ```
- It sends the puzzle to the frontend with an HTML form that contains a hidden input field with the `puzzleID` and a visible input field `answer`.
- The user submits the form with their answer in a POST request to the backend.
- The backend looks up the answer from its database (based on the `puzzleID` in the POST request) and compares that to the `answer` from the POST request. It also checks whether the deadline has not yet passed.
- If the answer was correct and in time, then the *backend* updates the gold in the user record.