# Which is better when writing APIs in NodeJS for a web app? Validating JSON parameters in front end or in the API?

Tags: node.js, json, api

When building APIs do you leave validation of parameters to the front end or do you also validate in the API? I have been validating in my APIs but I hate how bloated they become.

In Node I find myself doing this all the time;

```
    if (JSON.parse(event.body).hasOwnProperty('user_id')) {
          var user_id = JSON.parse(event.body).user_id;
        }else{throw new Error('Parameter user_id is empty'); }
```

It works but its sucks to look at and I have not come across a better way. It also gets ugly when I have more than a couple parameters to parse.

So I guess the first question is, do you feel validation is needed in the API?

And the second question is, is there a better or simpler way to do it in NodeJS than how I am doing it?

Comment: Opinion-based questions aren't good fits here and are off-topic - see scope of Stack Overflow as defined in [help/on-topic]

Comment: 1.) Yes, a backend should validate incoming data; 2.) Maybe [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) helps out.

Comment: Validation must always happen in the API (in the backend), as motivated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72130824/16462950).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `joi` as suggested by @pzaenger or any other package to make validation easier.

And yes, the backend should always validate anything that it receives from the world via frontend or anywhere. Frontend validation is most of the time optional, and is done primarily to provide good user experience, and to reduce the number of requests containing invalid data to server. But server should always validate regardless of frontend.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who ever searches for this. I asked around and this is a method that was suggested by someone and it has cleaned up our code massively.

First we do a simple default `|| {}` to null when we deconstruct the incoming json values into variables

```
//parse event body and deconstruct into variables
let data = JSON.parse(event.body);
//parse individual sections or nothing if no section was sent
let {user_id, other_param1, other_param2} = data || {};
```

Then in the switch for event.httpMethod we just validate the parameters we want for each.

```
switch (event.httpMethod) {

  case 'GET':
        //either of these can be used for
        if(!user_id || !other_param1|| !other_param2) {
          throw new Error(body.error = 'Missing required parameter')}
      break;
```

This has reduced the lines of code validating parameters in our APIs by about 60 percent and the code is much more readable and logical.