# Prevent REST API to be called with forged payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, security

This is a security problem that I'm trying to deal with. I'm having a Nodejs REST Api and React frontend. The user logs in and server issues a JWT token which is stored in localstorage.

Now there is a game which user plays and as the game finishes the high score is recorded in database with POST api by passing high score in body of the request.

Later my application uses these high scores to award prizes to user so there is a monetary thing involved.
Suppose the user is malicious, he came to know about my POST api structure, he got token from local storage he knows how I'm sending high score in payload.He went to postman and hit the api, as I'm using CORS he gets an error. Now he comes to browser and opens console on my website and from there he calls the API and everything worked. He is now holding the high score and winning the prizes unethically.

Any suggestions what's wrong with this particular implementation or how it can be resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Not possible. If you want the high score determination to be tamper-proof you must carry it out on the server, not on the client. See also [When doing a booking system, where would it be better to do? Back end or front end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72130746/when-doing-a-booking-system-where-would-it-be-better-to-do-back-end-or-front-e).

Longer answer: You have not told us how the game itself is implemented. Does it leave any traces on the server other than the score? Because if you only want to store the score on the server, how could an honest player ever prove to the server that they earned the score by playing by the rules? The answer to this clearly depends on what the game is all about. Without knowing the rules of the game, I cannot imagine a better answer.

Comment: The game is implemented in unity webGL. Whereas we have nodejs REST APIs for user login and signup process and we are using them in our main app and are planning to use them in game also for auth process.