Limit value of input on page load
I've got a shopping cart where I need to limit the quantity of certain items. The quantity amount is an input number field.
Using a combination of max and onchange attributes, and the following javascript stops a customers from increasing the amount beyond the limit (15).
function limiter(input) { if (input.value > 15) input.value = 15; };
However, it's still possible for a customer to add a product to the cart twice (from the product page), with a total quantity that exceeds the limit. As long as they don't then adjust the quantity input in the cart, it wont be changed back down to 15.
How can I get javascript to check and then limit the input value to 15 when the page loads? (I can apply an ID to the relevant input element to help target it.)
Thanks in advance.

You cannot enforce anything with client-side Javascript, because the client can always be manipulated by the user. Enforcement must be done on the server, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72130746/when-doing-a-booking-system-where-would-it-be-better-to-do-back-end-or-front-e.

Thanks but it's not a critical restriction. If a customer managed to manipulate it, it's not the end of the world — the order would just need to updated manually later. Can you help with the above javascript?

Consider the DOMContentLoaded event.
